# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException Error

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I am having trouble with the following assignment:

> "Write a program to accept any two dates in the form of month day year (8 23 2000), separated by spaces, and calculate the total number of days that has elapsed between the two dates, inclusive of the beginning and ending days.  Remember that leap year is a year divisible by 4, except for centennial years, which must be divisible by 400, such as 1600 or 2000 (1800 is not a leap year).  You can test your program with any typed in dates (or dates stored in a file) but it must finally run with the  data shown below. System output on the screen is acceptable."

I have this code so far and it compiles:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Project3
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

  int m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("dates.txt"));

  for(int i = 0 ; i < 6; ++i)
  {

     m1 = scan.nextInt();
     d1 = scan.nextInt();
     y1 = scan.nextInt();
     m2 = scan.nextInt();
     d2 = scan.nextInt();
     y2 = scan.nextInt();

     System.out.println("The total number of days between the dates you entered are: " + x(m1,    m2, d1, d2, y1, y2));
  }
  } 
   public static int x (int m1, int d1, int y1, int m2, int d2, int y2) 
  {
  int total = 0;
  int total1 = 0;
  int total2 = 0;

  if( m1 == m2 && y1 == y2)     
  {                             
     total = d2 - d1 +1;
  }

  else if ( y1 == y2 )
  {
     total = daysInMonth( m2 , y2 ) - d1 + 1;
  }

  for(int i = m1; i < m2 ; ++i)  
  {
     total1 += daysInMonth( m2, y2 );
  }

  for (int i = y1; i < y2; i++)
  {
     total2 += daysInYear ( y2 );
  }

  total += total1 + total2;
  return total;
 }

//Methods       
 public static boolean isLeap(int yr)
{
  if(yr % 400 == 0)
     return true;
  else if (yr % 4 == 0 && yr % 100 !=0)
     return true;
  else return false;

 }

  public static int daysInMonth( int month , int year)
 {  
  int leapMonth;

  if (isLeap(year) == true)
  {
     leapMonth = 29;
  }
  else
  {
     leapMonth = 28;
  }

  switch(month)
  {
     case 1:
     case 3:
     case 5:
     case 7:
     case 8:
     case 10:
     case 12: return 31;
     case 4:
     case 6:
     case 9:
     case 11: return 30;
     case 2: return leapMonth;
     }
   return 28;     
  }

 public static int daysInYear(int year)
 { 
  if (isLeap(year))
     return 366;
  else 
     return 365;

 }
}
```

The problem I am having is my output for the dates in the data file are incorrect.
I input these two dates `7 4 1776` and `1 1 1987` and get `723795` instead of the correct answer `76882`. 
Any other dates I input, they are also incorrect.

This is the error I get as well.

> The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 723795
>       Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
>       at Project3.main(Project3.java:15)

The data file:

```
7 
4 
1776        
1 
1 
1987
```

Please, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I've cleaned up his question title, getting rid of the unnecessary words.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks. It wouldn't let me change the title.

Comment: What does your data file look like?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the numbers are written underneath each other on separate lines 
7 
4 
1776  
1 
1 
1987

Comment: Somone, post the data file with your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you call the function x, you are passing the parameters in wrong sequence. The function is declared as x(m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2), but you are calling x(m1, m2, d1, d2, y1, y2). This was hard to find out. :)

Also, I've cleaned up the code based on your original code. Note that you need to use the variable "i" in the loop instead of "y1" or "m2"

For example,

```
for(int i = m1; i < m2 ; ++i)  
{
  total1 += daysInMonth( m2, y2 );
}
```

This code has no meaning. You wanted to use daysInMonth(i, y2);

Here is my suggestion:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    int m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("dates.txt"));

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 6; ++i)
    {

        m1 = scan.nextInt();
        d1 = scan.nextInt();
        y1 = scan.nextInt();

        m2 = scan.nextInt();
        d2 = scan.nextInt();
        y2 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The total number of days between the dates you entered are: " + x(m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2));
    }
} 
public static int x (int m1, int d1, int y1, int m2, int d2, int y2)  {
    int total = 0;
    total = d2 - d1 + 1;
    if (y1 == y2) {
        for(int i = m1; i < m2 ; ++i) {
            total += daysInMonth(i, y2);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = m1; i <= 12; i++) {
            total += daysInMonth(i, y1);
        }
        for (int i = y1+1; i < y2; i++) {
            total += daysInYear(i);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < m2 ; i++) {
            total += daysInMonth(i, y2);
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

The result is:

```
java Project3
The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 76882
```

Here is the entire code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Project3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {

      int m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2;
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("dates.txt"));

      for(int i = 0 ; i < 6; ++i)
      {

          m1 = scan.nextInt();
          d1 = scan.nextInt();
          y1 = scan.nextInt();

          m2 = scan.nextInt();
          d2 = scan.nextInt();
          y2 = scan.nextInt();

          System.out.println("The total number of days between the dates you entered are: " + x(m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2));
      }
  } 
public static int x (int m1, int d1, int y1, int m2, int d2, int y2)  {
    int total = 0;
    total = d2 - d1 + 1;
    if (y1 == y2) {
        for(int i = m1; i < m2 ; ++i) {
            total += daysInMonth(i, y2);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = m1; i <= 12; i++) {
            total += daysInMonth(i, y1);
        }
        for (int i = y1+1; i < y2; i++) {
            total += daysInYear(i);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < m2 ; i++) {
            total += daysInMonth(i, y2);
        }
    }
    return total;
}

//Methods       
 public static boolean isLeap(int yr)
{
  if(yr % 400 == 0)
     return true;
  else if (yr % 4 == 0 && yr % 100 !=0)
     return true;
  else return false;

 }

  public static int daysInMonth( int month , int year)
 {  
  int leapMonth;

  if (isLeap(year) == true)
  {
     leapMonth = 29;
  }
  else
  {
     leapMonth = 28;
  }

  switch(month)
  {
     case 1:
     case 3:
     case 5:
     case 7:
     case 8:
     case 10:
     case 12: return 31;
     case 4:
     case 6:
     case 9:
     case 11: return 30;
     case 2: return leapMonth;
     }
   return 28;     
  }

 public static int daysInYear(int year)
 { 
  if (isLeap(year))
     return 366;
  else 
     return 365;

 }
}
```

Comment: hey! That sounds great and thank you for finding my error. I am having another problem. It is weird that when I copy and paste your suggestion, it won't compile! Here is the error that I am getting:  "   Project3.java:45: error: reached end of file while parsing
} "

Comment: You probably missed the last "}" when you copy & paste the code?

Comment: when I add another "}" I get this error Project3.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
            total += daysInMonth(i, y2);
                     ^
  symbol:   method daysInMonth(int,int)
  location: class Project3

Comment: Let me add the entire code that was compiled with no problem.

Comment: Ok, I got everything in the data file and it compiles The only thing is it gives me the output and this error still:

Comment: entered are: 76882
The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 60
The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 18
The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 738
The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 6726
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at Project3.main(Project3.java:15)

Comment: It is because your code requires 6 data sets, but you only have 5 data sets in the file.

Comment: I do have 6:     7 4 17761 1 1987 
2 1 1983 3 15 1984 
7 7 1983 9 4 1983  
7 3 1983 7 20 1983  
12 25 1990 12 31 1992 
5 23 1996  10 21 2014

Comment: Are you sure? mine shows no error with your dataset.   The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 76882
The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 409
The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 60
The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 18
The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 738
The total number of days between the dates you entered are: 6726

Comment: I made a new one. I got it. Thank you so much!!